# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Users.[USERNAME].[PATH]' on Brownie run command

Tags: modulenotfounderror, brownie

After I've created a new project with `brownie init` I compiled a contract and try to run script for deployment with `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`.

But I've got;

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Users.[USERNAME].[PATH]'

```
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Users.[userName].Documents.Git.solidity-web3'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

*P.S. After I moved the project folder outside the **'Users.[USERNAME].[PATH]'** directory to **'C:'** it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, brownie doesn't like to have a "." in the path of the file. I assume your folder name includes one. So the only option is to rename it.

Comment: Nope. There is no '.' on any folder name.

Comment: It works for me! You are a lifesaver thanks!