# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Code.web3'

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py, brownie

I have a brownie project setup and am trying to run `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`, the script simply has a main function with a hello world print statement. When I run the command, I run into this error.

```
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrowniewSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 53, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Code.web3'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

Note : I have web3 installed and am running python 3.10.4

Comment: Would you mind adding your code? What you have provided is insufficient to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I just had the same issue,check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604220/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-users-username-path-on-brownie-run-co